# spring does not reginase "redirect:/path" returning a simple string

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc

The redirect just returns a simple string. It does not recognise the redirect.
The response just print "redirect:/getUser/"
Can you help me?
thanks already.

[the return should be the list of user with the new user added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XP89x.png)

```
@Slf4j
@RestController
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    UserService userService;

    @GetMapping(value = "/getUser", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
    public List<UserDTO> getUsers() throws Exception {
        List<UserDTO> oListUsers = new ArrayList<UserDTO>();

        try {
            oListUsers = userService.findAll();

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            log.error("Error getUsers. Cause: " + ex.getMessage());
            throw new Exception("Data can not be retrieved. Cause: " + ex.getMessage());
        }

        return oListUsers;
    }

    @PostMapping("/createUser")
    public String createUser(@Valid @RequestBody UserDTO newUser) throws Exception {

        try {
            userService.save(newUser);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            log.error("Error createUser. Cause: " + ex.getMessage());
            throw new Exception("Data can not be save. Cause: " + ex.getMessage());
        }

        return "redirect:/getUser/";
    }
}
```

Comment: createUser method is not following REST . i would suggest it to change accordingly and return ResponseEntity

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest below changes .

```
@PostMapping("/user")
    public ResponseEntity createUser(@Valid @RequestBody UserDTO newUser) throws Exception {
       UserDTO createdUser;
        try {
            createdUser=userService.save(newUser);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            log.error("Error createUser. Cause: " + ex.getMessage());
            throw new Exception("Data can not be save. Cause: " + ex.getMessage());
        }

        return new ResponseEntity(createdUser);
    }
```

and provide other API to list all the users

Comment: Thanks Mandar, but is the no way to do with strings ("return "redirect:/getUser/")?

Comment: @LuisAntônioCostaFilho yes possible with strings too ("return "redirect:/getUser/")?

Comment: but does not work with me. Just print the string url.